# xampp working on wrong port

Tags: networking, apache2, xampp

I am converting an old site from Windows to Ubuntu using XAMPP. I have changed as little as possible in `httpd.conf` and added a minimal number of vhosts (detail below). There are two virtual hosts: a 'default' on port 80 and another on port 8000.

This is the vhosts file:

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
# Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias 135sbr
  ErrorLog "/opt/lampp/htdocs/error.log"
  DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/135sbr/"
  <Directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs/135sbr/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

#
Listen 8000

<VirtualHost *:8000>
    ServerName 135sms
    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/135sms/"
    <Directory  "/opt/lampp/htdocs/135sms/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The primary host - that is I assume, on port 80 gives 'object not found' for any access - INDEX.HTML doezs not work however, if I change it to localhost:8000 - it does.

I have this in httpd.conf:

```
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 80
# Listen 8000
```

i.e. it is mostly at default.

I don't understand how this can be access through port `8000` ... and why not through port `80`. I've checked a number of top level docs and it is the same throughout - I can see it through port `8000` and not through `80` (I assume the browser is looking at port `80`).

Can someone please point me in the right direction ... this should be obvious but it is not to me.

BTW `localhost/phpmyadmin` works but localhost does not (that is, no dashboard)

It might also be relevant ... I use hard-coded addresses to access the server and internal docs -- I know -- bad practice but for this hidden site, it works OK.

Many thanks
P
apologies for the formatting ...I'll figure that out.

Comment: By "hard-coded addresses" do you mean IP addresses or custom domains in an `/etc/hosts` file on the client machines? Have you confirmed that the directories exist and that permissions are correct? One of the most annoying issues with XAMPP is that it will try to handle incomplete/incorrect configurations by doing a bunch of things in the background without reporting issues. This makes tracking problems down much harder. You may find that a proper LAMP/LAPP installation will be easier to configure maintain.

Comment: thanks for your response. fixed now. I don't know how this was caused but it was in the vhosts file,,, I replaced that with one from a working system and now it works. I still can't see how it could cause the wrong port to be used. Thanks also for the xampp advice..carefully noted.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response. The problem is now fixed though I don't know what it actually was, it was certainly my confirmation error.
Pb